# What is the maximum size of an independent set in the following tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

I am trying to solve this and getting 7 as an answer, but can anyone confirm my answer?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of the independent set in this tree is 10.

This can be obtained by the following dynamic programming over tree: for each vertex, we will calculate the maximum independent set of a subtree of this vertex with this vertex included and without. Then, if this vertex is not included we will pick a maximum of 2 values from each child and sum them, and for this vertex included we pick non-included values from children, sum them and add 1 (current vertex). For leaves, our dynamic programming is, obviously, (0, 1).

That is my manual calculation of this dynamic programming. Values are written in the form (not included, included) near each vertex, and colored vertices are the maximum independent set.[image: The solution]